# how to resolve header order issue

Tags: c++, header, include

I have the following problem: 
My code relies on two external packages

- [EIGEN](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) (Headers only)
- [IAU SOFA](http://www.iausofa.org/) (static library + headers)

If I write the following code:

```
#include "sofa.h"
#include "Eigen/Dense"
```

I get the following error messages:

> ```
> /some_path/sofam.h:85:18: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant  #define DAYSEC ( 86400.0 ) ...
> ```

and many more lines of errors.

However, if I change the order of the includes it compiles:

```
#include "Eigen/Dense"
#include "sofa.h"
```

works fine.

**What is causing the problem?**

My main problem is that I do not know how this behavior is called so I cannot really google it effectively. 
It is not an option to change any of the source code of EIGEN or IAU SOFA (since they are maintained by other groups and we regularly update them from their webpage)

It is also not an option to just fix it once and never touch it again. The order of our header files is automatically rearranged to be in alphabetic order which is messing up everything every time we commit any change and we regularly use an `optimize imports` algorithm which is also changing the includes automatically.

Comment: Looks like one lib is declaring a macro that is conflicting with another variable/macro in the other lib. Its one of the reasons why global macros are bad.

Comment: I agree, but how can I fix it

Comment: Take a look into the header files. sofa.h seems to have checks in it to detect macros that exist already and eigen seems to be rather selfcentered and ignorant with regards to other code.

Comment: You will probably need to implement some kind of hack to work around it, there is no easy solution here. How about grouping these conflicting headers in another header, disabling `optimize imports` and header reordering for that particular file and then including that extra header instead of eigen and sofa separately.

Comment: You could create a composite header that adds them always in the right order and use it when both are required.

Comment: Why does `#include "Eigen/Dense"` not end with .h e.g. `#include '"Eigen/Dense.h'`?

Comment: @const_ref I will think about it. The problem is that I do not include both headers in the same file: SOFA is included through another class import while EIGEN will be included through a different class import...

Comment: Can you forward declare types? If so then you do not need to include headers in the header files and you wont hit issues with headers pulling in a bunch of other headers

Comment: @nivpeled good point. because they do it this way in the EIGEN  tutorials and I simply copied it from there. I will check if this has some influence. EDIT: because it is no .h file ;-)

Comment: @const_ref I fear this is not an option without big changes in our code... I will think about it

Comment: Its probably worth doing, even just for the reduction on compile times.

Comment: Concerning _My main problem is that I do not know how this behavior is called_: I did [google "macro namespace pollution"](https://www.google.com/search?q=macro+namespace+pollution) (the 3 terms which came in my mind first when I read your question) and I found a nice article describing what I myself once experienced similar: [Reducing Preprocessor Namespace Pollution](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/reducepnp.html).